# How to stop self-hosted WCF service upon unhandled errors?

Tags: wcf, error-handling, self-hosting

I have a self-hosted WCF service that is running as a Windows Service. For the tests, I'm running it as a console application.

I'd like to catch all unhandled exceptions that happen in the service and shutdown the host. I'd like to catch all non FaultExceptions that happen when producing a response, but also all exceptions that are thrown in "idle mode" - i.e. thrown from some worker threads.

Unfortunatelly, I can't handle the exceptions neither by IErrorHandler (not called), nor by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException (not raised).

Any clues?

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TestServiceBahavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBahavior" name="WcfErrorHandling.TestService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8001/TestService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfErrorHandling.ITestService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher;

namespace WcfErrorHandling
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface ITestService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string SayHello(string param);
    }

    public class TestService : ITestService
    {
        public string SayHello(string param)
        {
            if (param == "ae")
                throw new ArgumentException("argument exception");
            if (param == "fe")
                throw new FaultException("fault exception");
            return "hello";
        }
    }

    public class TestHost : ServiceHost, IErrorHandler
    {
        public TestHost()
            : base(typeof(TestService))
        {
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += 
                (sender, ea) => UnhandledExceptionHandler(ea.ExceptionObject as Exception);

            Open();
            foreach (var channelDispatcher in ChannelDispatchers.OfType<ChannelDispatcher>())
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(this);
        }

        public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        public bool HandleError(Exception error)
        {
            if (!(error is FaultException))
                UnhandledExceptionHandler(error);
            return true;
        }

        private void UnhandledExceptionHandler(Exception ex)
        {
            Close();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testHost = new TestHost();
            testHost.Start();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
            testHost.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem, this solved it for me:

Make your service implement this interface:

```
public class MyService : System.ServiceModel.Description.IServiceBehavior
```

Implement it like this:

```
    public void AddBindingParameters(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher channel in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers) { channel.ErrorHandlers.Add(new ErrorHandler()); }
    }

    public void Validate(System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        return;
    }
```

And add this class:

```
public class ErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
   bool IErrorHandler.HandleError(Exception error)
    { return true; }
   void IErrorHandler.ProvideFault(Exception error, System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageVersion version, ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message fault)
    { return;  }
}
```

Now set a breakpoint on HandleError.. it will show you the exception

Comment: Your config is not set up to use the IErrorHandler you're written. @Flores is pointing you in the right direction. Look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx) to see how to properly configure it.

Comment: I'm using this without any config file

Comment: Sorry, should have made my comment clearer. The config shown in the **question** isn't configured to add the IErrorHandler behavior extension which is why his error handler wasn't getting hit. The sample service code in the this answer also implements a service behavior which adds the IErrorHandler implementation so a config file entry is not needed.

Comment: I have fixed a couple of typos in the code above. In my code, I used the HandleError to log the error and then return 'false' so that the specific faulting session would be closed. This way, my WCF Self Hosted service is more resilient to badly behaving clients.