# Windows Service hosting WCF - Can I stop Windows Service from within a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I have a Windows Service hosting a WCF service. If something goes really wrong in my WCF service I'd like to stop the Windows Service. I could try and force it to stop by shelling out and using net stop but is there a 'nicer' way to do this?

WCF is run the usual way from windows service:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    if (serviceHost != null)
    {
        serviceHost.Close();
    }

    ///WCF service hosted
    serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(XXXService));


    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136457/how-to-stop-self-hosted-wcf-service-upon-unhandled-errors

Comment: I think you might want to have a look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, we have implemented our self-hosted WCF Windows Services with a “Service Host Controller” class that holds references to the ServiceHost objects and is therefore responsible for “starting”/opening and “stopping”/closing the service host object.  In addition, the “Service Host Controller” class implements a delegate that allows the hosted objects to call back into the controller and initiate a graceful shutdown.